# Change font in Console.app in macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, font, console

How do I change the font used in macOS Sierra? Has Apple actually taken away the ability to set the font?

Currently in macOS Sierra the [`SFMono`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Francisco_(sans-serif_typeface)) font bundled with the app seems to be in use. I cannot find any menu item for fonts, nor can I find any toolbar button available for accessing fonts.

The context-menu for the content of a Console.app window offers a `Font` > `Show Fonts` item. The standard font-picker appears. But choosing fonts in the picker has no effect on the Console.app window.

Comment: It looks, like there's still no solution for Console.app here in 2020 (facepalm). Fortunately we can just use commandline `tail`, like `tail -f /var/log/some.log`. Viva la Terminal! :D

Comment: `tail` won't help you with the MacOS new logging system (os_log) that does NOT save logs in text files. you could use the "log stream" or "log show" in Terminal and see logs - but Console.app does MUCH MORE than this. It gives you queries and filters, and selection of columns, and what-not. Terminal is no replacement for Console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the font for Console.app OOTB with macOS 10.12.x.

Console.app uses the font that is located in the application itself ^. If you delete it, which is not recommended, the default font it will revert to Helvetiva.

^ `/Applications/Utilities/Console.app/Contents/Resources/Fonts/`.

Comment: This is not answering any of the OP's question - about display SIZE and not font/type.  The SFMono embedded in Console.app, is a normal font (available also independent of the Console.app) that can render in any size - so there's no point in replacing it with a different font. The issue is NOT with the font.

Comment: @MottiShneor No, I did not ask about size. I was indeed asking to swap out the font for another. I paid money for the [*Pragmata*](https://fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro/) font by Fabrizio Schiavi, a distinctly better monospaced font. So I’d like to use it in Console app.

Comment: Sorry then... my bad. I would guess you could replace the app internal font resource with your own - but that would break Console.app code-signing and I think some Apple apps now are even protected by SIP against ANY change, except by MacOS software update mechanism.

Comment: It's me who want to increase the font size, without success...